# AJAX calls for different users

Tags: ajax, json, web

So basically, i have a web app. And when a users enter, and gives some input, what he sees changes based on his input, with content from the DB.
The content that he sees, is taken from the DB and stored in a .json file, which is then later used to display to the user.

My question is...where do i store that info taken from the DB(in .json) for every user?...
Right now my JS looks like this...

```
$.getJSON('HTTP://LOCALHOST:8093/file.json')....
```

I can't use the same "file.json" for every users, because if i have 3 users using my app simultaneously, it won't work...

Comment: You could dynamically generate the json result for different users.

Comment: $.getJSON('HTTP://LOCALHOST:8093/fileUserId.json')....    So, do you mean something like have a file with the name file+User_id.json for every user?    Or not a file, let's say that i export the json for a user to HTTP://LOCALHOST:8093/UserId.json')

Comment: Instead of generating a seperate file generate a web page with the results.Example: http://graph.facebook.com/mat

Comment: Ok so basically you say something like my second option, I need a webpage for every user...because i can't use http://graph.facebook.com/mat for all users...   So then comes another small question...when i say the source of data in ajax like $.getJSON('HTTP://LOCALHOST:8093/mat.json')....can i change it dynamically too?...so if the current user is Alex, it should be like $.getJSON('HTTP://LOCALHOST:8093/Alex.json')...And if yes..how?:)

Comment: You dont have to manually create each and every json file.One one page itself you can display the data from the database.like [link]http://localhost:8093/index.php?username=mat
.Just create the index.php to generate the data.

Comment: ok i get that...but how do i tell JS, that the link for the current AJAX call is localhost:8093/index.php?username=mat ...? how do i put localhost:8093/index.php?username=mat  in the $.getJSON call?

Comment: If you were using PHP you could use <a data="<?php echo $username; ?>">Matt</a>.In javascript
$('a').click(function(){
     var username = $(this).attr('data');
      $.getJSON('HTTP://LOCALHOST:8093/'+username);
});